# black edges scatter around my imported mesh

Tags: modeling

I have recently imported my new base mesh for my model from maya. I tried to apply materials but even with the default mat, i could still see through my mesh. this happened with several quads around my model. i went on edit mode in blender and checked the mesh and i saw these unusual black edges in the areas the issue happened. i have no idea how to fix this, i just assume that my mesh has some problems with normal faces. last time i checked my mesh didnt have any overlapping verts or edges. Please help me resolve this problem.
[image]

Here's the mesh i just uploaded to blenderexchange:
[image]

Comment: are you 100% sure there are no double vertices, distorted edges, or maybe the mesh is open? Perhaps you could upload your .blend file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and [edit] the question to add the link.

Comment: @Luciano i have just uploaded the blender scene. please have a look to see the issue. i didn't include any material though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The black edges are normal edges, while all teal edges have the *sharp* flag set. So just select all edges, and open the edge menu with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. Select **Clear Sharp**, or **Mark Sharp**, depending of what you try to achieve.